# Suggest class names for an Event Booking system

Tags: c#, naming

I'm writing an Event Booking system in C#, which is vexing me greatly because "event" and "delegate" are reserved words. "Delegate" I've changed to "Attendee", but I can't think of an alternative name for the Event class (and instances thereof). The best I've come up with is "Happening", which is a little bit 1970s for my liking. Plus, the classes will be exposed via a customer API so I have to use professional terminology.

Any suggestions would be most gratefully received.

Edit: it is mainly the naming of instances and parameters that is bothering me:

```
public Booking CreateBooking(Event event, Person person);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use a C# reserved word, you can prefix it with '@'.

E.g.

```
public class @class
{
  ...
}
```

Use with caution...

Answer (score 2):

I would just go with Event. Type names are case-sensitive, so there is a distinction between event and Event. It is (in my humble opinion) the least confusing and most clear solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally just use `Event`. That doesn't come up as a *type* name very often. One alternative *might* be `Meeting` but it depends on what kind of events you're talking about.

Event really *is* the right name in the business domain here, for calendars in general.

If you've got recurrent events though, you'll also have exceptions. They're fun - is an `EventException` an exception to a recurrent event, or a failure to do something with an exception?

None of this can even *touch* fun with time zones though.

Answer (score 1):

But, event is a keyword, not Event (case sensitivity).  Why not use Event?  It seems like it is the best name for the job.

Answer (score 0):

C# is case sensitive, why not go with "Event" (capital E)?

Answer (score 0):

[Event at thesaurus.reference.com](http://thesaurus.reference.com/the?q=event)

Or think about using `Event` and `@event`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always fall back to old-school naming by pre-pending your classes with a "C" (for Class)

CEvent,CDelegate,CMyClass