# Suggestions wanted: What should I name a class that represents a real-life "event"?

Tags: naming

I need to define a class that represents a real-life event -- like a "movie premier", "party", etc. I will be creating a set of database objects to store the data for each event and define relationships with other data we have (e.g. venue, people, etc.).

The word "event" has a different meaning in the context of software, so I'd like to name the class something other than "event".

Any ideas on another name?

This [related post](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/752040/) asks a similar question, but I think all of the suggestions lack creativity -- basically `@event`, the case-sensitive name `Event` or use the old-school naming convention `CEvent`. Technically good solutions, but they don't help when discussing the data objects with peers (my speech and listening abilities are case-insensitive) and don't convey any information on how the class is not an event in the traditional use of the term.

Comment: Something that implements IAttendable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option would be `CalendarEvent`, to make it obvious that this is a real-world event tied to a given date.

Comment: I agree, CalendarEvent makes the most sense IMO.

Comment: SocialFunction :D That way you know it's something obligatory.

Comment: At this point it is going to be named MediaEvent.  In the context of our product, all the events we deal with are celebrity events -- movie premiers, award shows, events with red carpets, filming on set of TV shows/movies, etc.  We arrived at the name following the same basic principal that came up with CalendarEvent.

Comment: Cool. I'm glad I was (somewhat) helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

Activity come to mind.

Answer (score 4):

How about **Happening** or **Occasion**?

Answer (score 3):

Normally I'd recommend function, but it too has specific meanings in the context of software. ;)

Occasion might be a good synonym.

Answer (score 3):

The thesaurus lists the following as synonyms of the word *event*:

> accident, act, action, advent,
>   adventure, affair, appearance,
>   business, calamity, case, catastrophe,
>   celebration, ceremony, chance,
>   circumstance, coincidence,
>   conjuncture, crisis, deed,
>   development, emergency, episode,
>   experience, exploit, fact, function,
>   holiday, incident, juncture, marvel,
>   matter, milestone, miracle,
>   misfortune, mishap, mistake, occasion,
>   occurrence, pass, phase, phenomenon,
>   predicament, proceeding, shift,
>   situation, story, thing*, tide,
>   transaction, triumph, turn, wonder

Surely one of them would suffice... if not, you can prepend or wrap the word event to make it a non-keyword.  Something like @event or [event] although, I have to say that I don't personally like this practice even though it is syntactically permissable.

Comment: The idea of writing Class Mishap makes me chuckle :)

Comment: Mistake wouldnt be bad either.

Comment: lol @ eJames, it's better than the first one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered

Comment: Haha true. I pray that no one ever feels the need to names a class after me in that way.

Answer (score 3):

You could call it a 'Rendezvous'.  You could also just make up a word.  If this is a key concept in your domain you could abbreviate one of the other suggested names.  Things like:

- `CalenderEvent` becomes `Calvent`
- `SocialEvent` becomes `Socent`
- `RealWorldEvent` becomes `Revent`
- `HumanActivity` becomes `HAct`

Those quick examples might be terrible examples but they are short, don't collide with language or library names, and will become real meaningful words for you and your coworkers very quickly if you work with them frequently.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "Affair" or "Advent" -- you could also check the thesaurus:

http://thesaurus.reference.com/browse/event

Answer (score 2):

Entry or EventEntry are probably what I would go with.

Answer (score 2):

I can appreciate you want to avoid confusion with events in the programming sense, but my take on it is that maybe you should go with the most obvious name; program to your domain, and things stay readable and easier to design and maintain.

Comment: While normally I would agree Rob, as a VB developer I would have to disagree in this case.

Dim tEvent As Event = New Event
I just can't go along with that from a readability standpoint.  Obviously one can not Dim and Event, but being that Event has special meaning, you gotta think twice everytime you see that.

Comment: I disagree.  The word "event" has two different meanings in our problem space -- one is a real-life entity that we are trying to represent in code and the other is a programming construct. Even though "event" is the most obvious name, it's already taken. Having two totally different things named the same or very similar reduces readability & maintainability.

Additionally we have non-programmers who are aware of and/or interact with the data. I'd like to be able to share the same terminology with them, so we don't have to have a glossary or translation guide when communicating between teams.