# Class to log messages, event name?

Tags: c#, naming

Might be a very stupid, but a question. Might be a wrong, but a site.

Let say I have a class `Log` with the static methods `Start`,`Stop` and `Log`.

How would you call an event which occurs if something is calling `Log("...");` ?

For a last 20 minutes I stumble to give it a proper name. `Added` ? `Log` (but there is already method `Log`)? What would be the best intuitively understandable event name?

Comment: `OnLog` would be my choice.

Comment: I'm a little confused, are you just asking what to name your method? Voting to close, opinion based

Comment: @tnw Yes.  It's a reasonable question.

Comment: @DStanley, you and up-voters are wrong, because that would be a name for the method to rise an event (from inside or outside).

Comment: @basher No, its not, and there's a close option exactly for questions like this. EDIT as demonstrated by his comment, this is CLEARLY an opinion based question and won't lead to anything constructive. I beg you to argue that a discussion on method naming can be objective and fact-based

Comment: @tnw, yes, give me name what match some rules, intuitive, best for the coding..

Comment: @tnw, if it's hard to answer simple and straight-forward question, then simply down-vote and gogogo :-)

Comment: @Sinatr it's because the question doesn't work in the Q+A format.. how can you accept any answer over another if it's merely your opinion driving it? It's the same reason as to why "what's the best practice for.." questions are closed.

Comment: ... and there are questions where opinion is a key (and some of them have answers what are very general and helpful), to example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752040/suggest-class-names-for-an-event-booking-system?rq=1)

Comment: @Sinatr This question is none of those things. This is like asking what car someone likes best based *only on the name of the car*. There is no "right" answer to the question, it's simply the one you like the best.

Comment: @Sinatr And that's a question from 4 years ago. Nice try. StackOverflow is *a lot* different now than it was when that question was asked. Many new rules and guidelines for posting have been added since then, one of which is to close subjective, non-constructive questions like this.

Comment: If there can be no "exact", 100% correct and verifiable answer, then the question belongs on yahoo! and not here.

Comment: Or [`programmers.stackexchange.com`](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) for that matter. The whole site was made specifically for conceptual/subjective discussion questions. @Sinatr, questions like this should be directed there in the future.

Comment: @tnw, there is no private messages, so: 1) yes, you are right, only I (alone) need answer on this question, but question itself contains "event name", which may be searched for in the future by someone else; 2) on this site you can accept only 1 answer and usually you accept the best for you, not the one which is the best for everybody  ("Q+A format"), however, nothing prevents from having many answers and a lot of up-votes for right ones; 3) i knew from start what question will be disliked, but at least i got an answer (at cost of some down-votes), Anderei got my thanks,you got..satisfaction?

Comment: @Sinatr Sigh. Are you seriously arguing that since your question has words, and is therefore searchable, that it makes a valid question? I hope you realize literally 100% of questions ever asked on the site meet that criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some ideas:

```
Logging
LogEntryAdding
```

or, if event is fired after the logging:

```
Logged
LogEntryAdded
```

**Update.** As suggested by [Gene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640901/gene):

```
EntryAdding / EntryAdded
```

Comment: I'd go with `EntryAdded` to remove the redundancy and to improve the readability (`Log.EntryAdded += ...` instead of `Log.LogEntryAdded`).

Comment: Yes, event after logging occurs. `Logged` sounds the best so far.

Comment: After some thoughts (yes, I am still thinking, 30 min passed, omg), `EntryAdded` is a winner at this moment. I though myself about `Added`, but it looks crap as `Log.Added` (because there is no method to add something). And `Log.EntryAdded` sounds better and more clear.